# How PN junction diode is used as temperature sensor

Tags: sensor, diodes, pn-junction

I know the operation of PN junction diode. But I wonder how they use it as a temperature sensor.

Comment: Sorry, but a simple "diode temperature sensor" search turns up a ton of information, if you have a specific question, state the explicit doubt and show what you researched before.

Comment: ..and as you claim "to know the operation of a PN junction" you would be aware of the fact that with a constant current applied, the voltage across a diode or PN junction will decrease by approximately 1 to 2 mV/°C and that it is a fairly linear relationship. As Arsenal suggests do some research.

Comment: Peruse [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling#Variation_of_Forward_Voltage_with_Temperature)

Comment: This is a fine question to have in our archive.  +1

Comment: thank u very much for the answers. they were very useful to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**Effect of temperature on forward characteristics :**

The characteristics curve of a Si diode shifts to the left at the rate of -2.5 mV per degree centigrade change in temperature in forward bias region.

> Refer to the graph shown above. The curves are shown far apart just
>   for illustration purpose and are not to scale. The curve shifts to the
>   left at the rate of -2.5 mV per degree centigrade change in
>   temperature. Hence if the temperature increases from room temperature
>   (25° C) to 80° C, the voltage drop across the diode will be (80-25) x
>   2.5 mV = 137.5 mV.

Note:The values will change with respect to diodes,not all diodes are made up of same parameters and composition.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

The diode equation is

\$ I_D=I_0 \left( e^ \left(\frac{V_D}{nV_T} \right) - 1 \right)\$

and

\$  V_T= \frac{kT}{q}\$,

so every pn junction has a well defined temperature dependency.  Some junctions are optimized for this behavior, but it holds for every junction

Comment: Ok, I know, it's 2018, but you could have added that this behaviour that you refer to only occurs at constant current.